# XSLTProcessor.transformToFragment( ) returns null on Microsoft edge

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, microsoft-edge

I have the following line of code to transform a XMLfragment from two docs, this code works in Firefox and chrome with no problem, but whenever I use this in Edge, it is returning null (SchemaStylesheetObj is a XSLTprocessor object):

```
xmlFragment = SchemaStylesheetObj.transformToFragment(xmldoc, ownerDocument);
```

Both my xmldoc and ownerDocument has proper textContents,below is part of my XSLT file that I am using for the transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
            xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
            xmlns:doc="http://nwalsh.com/xsl/documentation/1.0"
            xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
            xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon"
            xmlns:dtbl="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/dtbl"
            xmlns:ptbl="http://nwalsh.com/xslt/ext/xsltproc/python/Table"
            xmlns:stbl="http://nwalsh.com/xslt/ext/com.nwalsh.saxon.Table"
            xmlns:xtbl="com.nwalsh.xalan.Table"
            xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
            xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:t="http://thresholds.data"
            xmlns:lip="http://listItemPrefix.data"
            xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            extension-element-prefixes="str"
            version="1.0">
            ....
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
            <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />

            <xsl:template name="debug_spec_version">
            <div class="debug_pane xslt_debug">Processed with 2361E v5.00  style sheet</div>
            </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

ownerDocument is being generated using the following line:

```
var ownerDocument = document.implementation.createDocument("", "test", null);
```

xmldoc is being generated as such:

```
var xmldoc = xmlparser.parseFromString(xmlContents, "text/xml");
```

The first few lines of xmlContents is as follows:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2013,    v.4002-->\n<!DOCTYPE macwp PUBLIC \"-//USA-DOD//DTD MIL-STD-2361 TM Assembly REV   E 5.0 20131101//EN\"\n \"production.dtd\">\n<?Pub Inc?>\n<macwp chngno=\"0\" wpno=\"A0002\">\n<wp.metadata><portionmark/>\n<proponent>\n<name></name>\n<address><city></city><state></state></address>\n</proponent>\n<tracking>\n<change.history>\n<author>\n<name>vansycke</name>\n<proponent>\n<name></name>\n<address><city></city><state></state></address>\n</proponent>\n</author>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You want to see the content of xmldoc and ownerDocument, is that what you meant?

Comment: Ok, so you meant that I need to put the content of those XML object up as well then...sorry I don't know what's important in those files that might be of interest.

Comment: Got it, added them to my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced this issue while working to make my application with EDGE compatible and after several hours I found its solution and root cause.

Root cause of failing transformToFragment is the below namespace used in your style sheet.

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
```

please remove this namespace and use

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I think you've got the right answer here madhwendar, but the eslt is in there for a reason.  YOu can't just take it out, it needs to be replaced, but with what?  For example., I use the exsl:node-set extension function and if I take out exsl then it won't work. Is there a msxml replacement?